# Uploading of fake images security concerns/prevention

Tags: php, image, security, upload, getimagesize

I am building a PHP web app and it includes image uploading. I've read about preventing the uploads of fake images. But what are fake images and how can they be used to attack a server?

Is it sufficient using the PHP function `getimagesize()` along with checking the file extension to eliminate all possible attacks through images?

Comment: If you have no idea what you are asking about it may be better to figure out it first. Otherwise you would not know if possible answers actually answer your question.

Comment: Checking the file extension does not prevent any one from uploading something else. Also I've never heard of fake images. Only images which have executable code inside them. They're valid images - but you should recreate the image completely on your side to eliminate executable code in images.

Comment: No, `getimagesize()` is not sufficient, and the filename extension check is useless. Sadly, I don't think there's a 100%-reliable way as even server-side MIME detection is extremely fragile.

Comment: You might want to read this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form

Comment: Thanks @CharlotteDunois, extremely helpful

Comment: That being said, rely on the `Fileinfo` extension to get the MIME-Type and compare it against a whitelist of allowed MIME-Types. `getimagesize` is nice, but not really built to detected the MIME-Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example of a fake image would be where someone uploads a PHP file instead of an image and then tricks the server in to executing it. There are several options for preventing this kind of attack, including preventing the user from picking the file extension used to store the image on the server and storing uploaded images outside of the document root (using `file_get_contents` to read them when needed).

Answer (score 0):

For a good explanation of what fake images are read @Chris explanation.

The intention of fake images is to put executable code on your server, so storing user uploaded images outside of the document root is a good idea. Another good idea is to check if a file is really a image.

Probably the fastest method to check if a file is a valid image:

```
function isValidImage($file) {
  return ( false === exif_imagetype($file) ) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php for further information and examples.

Comment: Is this more reliable than catching an Imagick exception? :)

Comment: Never compared both options but I can tell that `exif_imagetype()` does not consume a large amont of memory and is lightning fast.